# Given x0, x1, y0, y1, a function that has one fixed exponential shape

Tags: functions, exponential-function

for visualization sake I'm trying to come up with a function that looks like that:

[image]

I came up with this solution, but it fails when the ranges change. I also couldn't figure out how to make it start at y0.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What about this? $$f(x)=y_0+(y_1-y_0)\sqrt{\frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}}$$
But not the shape is not "exponential". Not even "logarithmic", as it's a square root. But you may adapt this to other functions.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much